# After migrating from JDK1.8 to openjdk11 getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jdk/internal/reflect/ConstructorAccessorImpl error

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4, java-11

while generating parser using antlr4-4.9.2-complete.jar,I am getting the below error

> ```
>  [java] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jdk/internal/reflect/ConstructorAccessorImpl
> [java]    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecuteJava.execute(ExecuteJava.java:194)
> [java]    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.run(Java.java:771)
> [java]    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.executeJava(Java.java:221)
> [java]    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.executeJava(Java.java:135)
> [java]    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.execute(Java.java:108)
> [java]    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
> [java]    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
> [java]    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> [java]    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
> [java]    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
> [java]    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
> [java]    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
> [java]    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
> [java]    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
> [java]    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> [java]    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
> [java]    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
> [java]    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
> [java]    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(MacroInstance.java:396)
> [java]    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
> [java]    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
> [java]    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> [java]    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
> [java]    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
> [java]    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
> [java]    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
> [java]    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
> [java]    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
> [java]    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:38)
> [java]    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
> [java]    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:440)
> [java]    at org.apache.tools.ant.AntBridge.call(AntBridge.java:61)
> [java]    at org.apache.tools.ant.AntBridge.call(AntBridge.java:17)
> [java]    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
> [java]    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
> [java]    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
> [java]    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
> [java] Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jdk/internal/reflect/ConstructorAccessorImpl
> [java]    at java.base/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.defineClass0(Native Method)
> [java]    at java.base/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.defineClass(Unsafe.java:1192)
> [java]    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.ClassDefiner.defineClass(ClassDefiner.java:63)
> [java]    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator$1.run(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:400)
> [java]    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator$1.run(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:394)
> [java]    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> [java]    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator.generate(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:393)
> [java]    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator.generateConstructor(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:92)
> [java]    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:55)
> [java]    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
> [java]    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
> [java]    at org.antlr.v4.automata.ParserATNFactory.newState(ParserATNFactory.java:724)
> [java]    at org.antlr.v4.automata.ParserATNFactory.createRuleStartAndStopATNStates(ParserATNFactory.java:663)
> [java]    at org.antlr.v4.automata.ParserATNFactory._createATN(ParserATNFactory.java:157)
> [java]    at org.antlr.v4.automata.LexerATNFactory.createATN(LexerATNFactory.java:105)
> [java]    at org.antlr.v4.Tool.processNonCombinedGrammar(Tool.java:384)
> [java]    at org.antlr.v4.Tool.process(Tool.java:359)
> [java]    at org.antlr.v4.Tool.processGrammarsOnCommandLine(Tool.java:318)
> [java]    at org.antlr.v4.Tool.main(Tool.java:162)
> [java]    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> ```
>
> Method)
> [java]    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> [java]    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> [java]    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
> [java]    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecuteJava.run(ExecuteJava.java:217)
> [java]    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecuteJava.execute(ExecuteJava.java:152)
> [java]    ... 36 more
> [java] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jdk.internal.reflect.ConstructorAccessorImpl
> [java]    at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.findClassInComponents(AntClassLoader.java:1366)
> [java]    at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.findClass(AntClassLoader.java:1315)
> [java]    at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.loadClass(AntClassLoader.java:1074)
> [java]    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
> [java]    ... 61 more
> [java] Java Result: -1
> [copy] error(114): TopoExpressionParser.g4:3:23: cannot find tokens file
> /home/patana1/workspace/trunk-build-java11/src/java/com/grammar/DefaultLexer.tokens

```
for the code

<macrodef name="generate-parser">
            <attribute name="grammar"/>
            <sequential>
                <property name="src.grammar.dir" location="${src.java.dir}/grammar" />
                <property name="src.grammar.generated.dir" location="${src.java.generated.dir}/grammar" />
    
                <java classname="org.antlr.v4.Tool" >
                    <classpath>
                        <pathelement path="${libs.dir}/antlr4-4.9.2-complete.jar" />
                    </classpath>
                    <arg value="-o" />
                    <arg value="${src.grammar.generated.dir}" />
                    <arg value="${src.grammar.dir}/@{grammar}.g4" />
                </java>
            </sequential>
        </macrodef>

<target name="generate-all-parsers">
        <generate-parser grammar="DefaultLexer"/>
</target>
```

Tried with latest antlr-4.13.0-complete.jar too but still same error can anyone please assist?

Comment: @user2340612 Already checked the link you suggested but its not clear on what is the exact issue and how can we resolve it?

Comment: The exact issue is that on Java 11, user code no longer permitted to access internal JDK classes **unless** you "open" the module via a command line option.  This is explained in the duplink **and** a workaround is given.

Comment: @StephenC  I did not understand  the workaround you referred to could you please let me know. How can we resolve this?

Comment: Well you first need to figure out what is loading that internal class.  I suspect it is a dependency of Antlr that has been included the "antlr4-4.9.2-complete.jar".  Or ... you could just check that you have updated the Antfile to >use< the newer version of the JAR file that you downloaded.

Comment: Checked the whole codebase and also i am seeing that jdk.internal.reflect.ConstructorAccessorImpl is their in openjdk11 too      
Binary file bin/jre-11/lib/server/libjvm.so matches
bin/jre-11/lib/classlist:jdk/internal/reflect/ConstructorAccessorImpl
Binary file bin/jre11/lib/server/libjvm.so matches
bin/jre11/lib/classlist:jdk/internal/reflect/ConstructorAccessorImpl
Binary file jmods/java.base.jmod matches
Binary file lib/modules matches
Binary file lib/src.zip matches
Binary file lib/server/libjvm.so matches
lib/classlist:jdk/internal/reflect/ConstructorAccessorImpl,
still error?

Comment: That's not the point.  Only the Java SE code should be using (i.e. naming) that class.  But *something else* is apparently attempting to use it too.  That attempt is what is leading to the class loading error.  There should be some trace of this in either your code, the Antlr JAR or some other 3rd-party dependency you are using.  And (possibly) in the full stacktrace for the classloader error as well.

Comment: Added full stack trace of the error.

Answer (score 0):

OK ... my initial diagnosis (in the comments) was wrong.

I think that the actual problem is in the Ant tool.  Specifically, Ant's custom classloader is triggering an old JDK bug: https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-6265952.  As you can see from the report, it is a long standing bug that only occurs in obscure circumstances.

The Ant issue is: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59556

Fortunately, the fix for you should be simple.  Upgrade to Ant 1.9.8 or 1.10.0 or later.   (The version of Antlr won't matter for this ... probably.)

Comment: I was able to resolve this by upgrading ANT. Thanks @Stephen C for the solution.